# Xamarin, SQLite : Don't know how to read System.Char

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I use the below code to search SQLite table. It works fine with Android 9. But I receive the below error in Android 10.
Where should I check or how can I make minimal change in the code so that it will work on Android 10 also.

**Edit 1:**
I'm using the following versions.

```
Xamarin.Forms v4.5.0.495
Xamarin.Essentials v1.3.1
sqlite-net-pcl v1.7.335
```

**Code:**

```
        public SearchPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    

            conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteMyConnection>().GetConnection();
            try
            {
                DisplayLines("");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }

        public void DisplayLines(string searchText)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
            {
                var details = (from x in conn.Table<QLines>() select x).ToList();
                myLines.ItemsSource = details;
                searchCount.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                var details1 = (from x in conn.Table<QLines>() where x.PartA.Contains(searchText) || x.PartB.Contains(searchText)  select x).ToList();
                myLines.ItemsSource = details1;
                searchCount.Text = "Matches found : " + details1.Count.ToString();
            }
            
        }

        private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayLines(e.NewTextValue);
        }
```

**Error:**

```
Don't know how to read System.Char
```

Comment: Which version of sqlite and xamarin.forms nuget packages that you use, please update all nuget packags to the lastest.

Comment: If I update the nuget packages, will it work with Android 9?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Please see Edit 1

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT sqlite having the latest version. If I update Xamarin, it wont work with Android 9

Comment: Could you share a demo that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT The flow is that: I have a search field. When the user type the characters, I show the matching lines in a list view from the db. The app was exiting without any message. To know the error, I added the ```try...catch```. The error message is from the ```Exception ex```

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I have debugged the code and found that the line ```.......ToList();``` causing the issue. But I wonder, usually new versions are compatible at least one previous version. If the code works in Android 10 and does not work in Android 9, it makes sense. The reverse does not make sense.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I got the issue the nuget package ```SQLite.Net.Core-PCL``` is deprecated. This package is handling LINQ like query on SQLite db. Suggested alternative is ```sqlite-net-pcl```. Might be, I need to revise the code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue.

The nuget package `SQLite.Net.Core-PCL` is deprecated. This package is handling LINQ like query on SQLite db. Suggested alternative is `sqlite-net-pcl`. Might be, I need to revise the code.

**Edit:** I have updated the Xamarin Form to version 5. And revised the code ( I used query instead of LINQ)